# cannot get to load images from a Link in android studio

Tags: android, drawable, picasso

I have this code, where it gets images from drawables  folder. I need to get images form  URLs. I think I can do it using `Picasso` and I tried and I could not nail it.

I have this code in my MainActivity:

```
public Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "image_name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private Drawable d1 = LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://uupload.ir/files/aud7_brickone.jpg");

private List<App> getApps() {
    List<App> apps = new ArrayList<>();
    apps.add(new App("Google+", d1, 4.6f));
    apps.add(new App("Google+", d1, 4.6f));
    apps.add(new App("Google+", d1, 4.6f));
    apps.add(new App("Google+", d1, 4.6f));
    apps.add(new App("Google+", d1, 4.6f));
    apps.add(new App("Google+", d1, 4.6f));
    apps.add(new App("Google+", d1, 4.6f));
    return apps;
}
```

and this is my adapter:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    App app = mApps.get(position);
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(app.getDrawable());
    holder.nameTextView.setText(app.getName());
    holder.ratingTextView.setText(String.valueOf(app.getRating()));
}
```

and here APP.JAVA

```
public class App {
    private Drawable mDrawable;
    private String mName;
    private float mRating;

    public App (String name, Drawable drawable, float rating){
        mName = name;
        mDrawable = drawable;
        mRating = rating;
    }

    public float getRating (){return mRating;}
    public Drawable getDrawable (){return mDrawable;}
    public String getName (){return mName;}
}
```

I need to the images from link like: http://uupload.ir/files/aud7_brickone.jpg

I cannot make it happen!

Comment: You want to get images from drawable folder or remote images?

Comment: remote! but i need it to be converted to "int"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to download an image from an URL. Check the funcion below:

```
public static Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String url) {
    try {
        InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "any_image_name");
        return d;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then simply show the returned drawable in your `ImageView`.

Don't forget to add the internet permissions in your manifest:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

You could also use this other method, combined with an AsyncTask or a background Thread:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
  ImageView bmImage;

  public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
      this.bmImage = bmImage;
  }

  protected Bitmap doInBackground(String url) {
      String urldisplay = url;
      Bitmap mIcon = null;
      try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
        mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
      } catch (Exception e) {
          Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      return mIcon;
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
      bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
  }
}
```

Then you call it wherever you need it with:

```
new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView))
        .execute("http://uupload.ir/files/aud7_brickone.jpg");
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thank you margabro, I used your first solution and now i have an error which says "Change 2nd Parameter of method "App"  from "int" to "drawable".

Comment: and when I do that I get another error which in my Adpater.Java class in onBindViewHolder code: holder.imageView.setImageResource(app.getDrawable());

Comment: the error in catlog is: Error:(45, 58) error: incompatible types: Drawable cannot be converted to int

Comment: That's because you are using the `setImageResource` method, which expects an `Integer` like `R.drawable.image` but you are giving it a `Drawable`. Use `holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(app.getDrawable());` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can use glide too,
Here is code

```
Glide.with(Your context).load(your image url).into(holder.Your imageview);
```

in your code

```
Glide.with(context).load(app.getDrawable()).into(holder.imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use either `Glide` or `Picasso`. But I prefer you `Picasso` for it because `Picasso` responses faster than `Glide`. Here is the code:

Import `Picasso` library and it works like charm:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("image url").into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 0):

u can use Imageloader its so better than picaso if u need get image from net u need get/put JSON u cant load or get image or text or anything without JSON

Comment: I get an error here: holder.imageView.setImageResource(app.getDrawable());   it says "Error:(45, 58) error: incompatible types: Drawable cannot be converted to int"